# TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, typeerror, stanford-nlp

I found the following code on a python tutorial website:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger

stanford_classifier = open("english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz")
stanford_ner_path = open("stanford-ner.jar")

st = StanfordNERTagger(stanford_classifier, stanford_ner_path)
```

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL7810/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/stanpar.py", line 9, in <module>
st = StanfordNERTagger(stanford_classifier, stanford_ner_path)
 File "C:\Users\DELL7810\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 180, in __init__
super(StanfordNERTagger, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DELL7810\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 63, in __init__
verbose=verbose)
File "C:\Users\DELL7810\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 721, in find_jar
searchpath, url, verbose, is_regex))
File "C:\Users\DELL7810\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 632, in find_jar_iter
if os.path.isfile(path_to_jar):
File "C:\Users\DELL7810\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
st = os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Comment: It looks like `StanfordNERTagger` wants file paths, which it will use to open the files, but you've given it open file handles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your problem

As you can see in this [**documentation page**](https://kite.com/python/docs/nltk.tag.StanfordNERTagger), `StanfordNERTagger` takes file paths as arguments:

```
StanfordNERTagger(path_to_model, path_to_jar)
```

Your code crashes because `open()` will give you file objects and this is not what `StanfordNERTagger` is expecting as arguments.

### Solution

Directly give your paths as arguments to `StanfordNERTagger`, like this:

```
st = StanfordNERTagger("C:\Users\DELL7810\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\stanford-ner-2018-02-27\classifiers\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz", "C:\Users\DELL7810\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\stanford-ner-2018-02-27\stanford-ner.jar")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you encountered the error in the title and you don’t have a filepath (perhaps because you want to pass an in-memory file-like object to a file loader that only accepts a file path), then one way to get around the issue is to create a temporary file, pass its path to the file loader and delete it later.

A specific example (on streamlit and langchain) goes like:

```py
import streamlit as st
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a file:", type=['pdf'])
loader = PyPDFLoader(uploaded_file)            # <---- TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not UploadedFile
```

Here `uploaded_file` is a file-like in memory which cannot be read by the loader. To get around the issue, create `NamedTemporaryFile` using the built-in `tempfile` module.

```py
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

bytes_data = uploaded_file.read()
with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp:  # open a named temporary file
    tmp.write(bytes_data)                      # write data from the uploaded file into it
    data = PyPDFLoader(tmp.name).load()        # <---- now it works!
os.remove(tmp.name)                            # remove temp file
```