# How can I use `langchain.document_loaders.PyPDFLoader` for pdf documents uploaded on StreamLit?

Tags: nlp, streamlit, langchain, nlp-question-answering

I am trying to build a webapp using StreamLit for reading documents (mainly pdf) and load the data using `langchain.document_loaders.PyPDFLoader` but I am ending up with an error as follows:

```
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list
```

followed by :

```
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/Users/shuhulhandoo/MetaGeeks/PDF-URL_QA/app.py", line 133, in <module>
    main()
File "/Users/shuhulhandoo/MetaGeeks/PDF-URL_QA/app.py", line 75, in main
    loader = PyPDFLoader(pdf)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/pdf.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(file_path)
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/pdf.py", line 42, in __init__
    if not os.path.isfile(self.file_path) and self._is_valid_url(self.file_path):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<frozen genericpath>", line 30, in isfile
```

In my code, I am actually uploading document (in streamlit) using:

```
import streamlit as st
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload PDF", type="pdf")
if uploader_file is not None:
    loader = PyPDFLoader(uploaded_file)
```

I am trying to use `PyPDFLoader` because I need the source of the documents such as page numbers to be saved up.

I tried adding the texts of each page in the pdf document page-wise as follows:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import streamlit as st

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload PDF", type="pdf")

if uploaded_file is not None:
    texts = ""
    reader = PdfReader(uploaded_file)
    for page in reader.pages:
        texts += page.extract_text()
```

But in this case, I have lost the information of the page number which I need in my case.

Comment: You can create a temporary file, pass its path to `PyPDFLoader` and remove the temp file after. [This answer has such a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77101087/19123103).

Answer (score 2):

`PyPdfLoader` takes in `file_path` which is a string. That means you cannot directly pass the uploaded file.

What you can do is save the file to a temporary location and pass the `file_path` to pdf loader, then clean up afterwards.

```py
# save the file temporarily
tmp_location = os.path.join('/tmp', file.filename)

loader = PyPDFLoader(tmp_location)
pages = loader.load_and_split()

# do whatever you need here

# clean up
if isinstance(file, Path):
   metadata.update({'file_name': file.name})
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But the file that I uploaded is on `streamlit` using `streamlit.file_uploader`. There is not path implied to the the function `streamlit.file_uploader`. How can I use `PyMuPDFLoader` to this?

Comment: You can use the `tmp_location` file path to save the stream lit file. Just check the documentation how to save the file. For example: it will be something like `file.save(tmp_location)`

Answer (score 0):

### By Uploading a file, you can get its content and write it to a temporary file. Like this :

```
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a PDF file", type="pdf")

if uploaded_file :

   temp_file = "./temp.pdf"
   with open(temp_file, "wb") as file:
       file.write(uploaded_file.getvalue())
       file_name = uploaded_file.name

   loader = PyPDFLoader(temp_file)
   documents = loader.load_and_split()

   text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1024, chunk_overlap=64)
   texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

   embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

   db = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings, persist_directory="db")
```

Remember , you can never get root path of any file from a webServer like Streamlit.