# How to solve "PermissionError: [Errno 13]" when running Streamlit application

Tags: python, streamlit, python-camelot

I'm creating an application using Streamlit where I need to extract a table from PDF file.

simplifyng the code, it looks like:

```
def extract_table(file,page,table_areas):
    table = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages=page,
                             table_areas=table_areas,
                             flavor='stream')    
    return table

if st.session_state.button:

    with st.form("form to upload file"):
        uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload file", type="pdf", key="uploaded_file")

        submitted = st.form_submit_button("Confirm and upload file")

if submitted:
    with NamedTemporaryFile(dir='.', suffix='.pdf') as f:
        f.write(st.session_state['uploaded_file'].getbuffer())
        df = extract_table(f.name, page_number, ['107', '420.1', '286', '262.1'])
```

But when I try to run the code I get the following error:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\ect_streamlit\tmpbv44t05n.pdf'

How could I solve this issue?

Sorry about possible mistakes in the question, it is my first time asking on StackOverFlow.

**My enviroment:**

OS: Windows 10 x64
Editor: VSCode

How I'm running file:
streamlit run efm.py --server.port 8080

**Error in detail:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ect_streamlit\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\ect_streamlit\efm.py", line 73, in <module>
    df_raw = extract_table(f.name, efm_page_number, ['107', '420.1', '286', '262.1']) # area x1,y1,x2,y2        
  File "C:\ect_streamlit\functions.py", line 12, in extract_table
    table = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages=page,
  File "C:\ect_streamlit\venv\lib\site-packages\camelot\io.py", line 113, in read_pdf
    tables = p.parse(
  File "C:\ect_streamlit\venv\lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py", line 169, in parse
    self._save_page(self.filepath, p, tempdir)
  File "C:\ect_streamlit\venv\lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py", line 107, in _save_page
    with open(filepath, "rb") as fileobj:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\ect_streamlit\\tmpbv44t05n.pdf'
```

Comment: Do you have permission to open the said pdf file ? Also might what to look at this : https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/402 they achieve to run it with administrator privileges

Comment: Is `C:\\ect_streamlit\\tmpbv44t05n.pdf` the correct path to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337167/typeerror-stat-path-should-be-string-bytes-os-pathlike-or-integer-not-io-t/77101087#77101087) I solved this issue.
Basically added "delete=False" as one of the arguments and removed the file created with "os.remove"

The code, now working:

```
def extract_table(file,page,table_areas):
    table = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages=page,
                             table_areas=table_areas, #x1,y1,x2,y2
                             flavor='stream')    
    
    return table[0].df

if st.session_state.button:

    with st.form("form to upload file"):
        uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload file", type="pdf", key="uploaded_file")

        submitted = st.form_submit_button("Confirm and upload file")

if submitted:
    with NamedTemporaryFile(dir='.', suffix='.pdf',delete=False) as tmp: 
        tmp.write(st.session_state['uploaded_file'].getbuffer())

        df_raw = extract_table(tmp.name, efm_page_number, ['107,420.1,286,262.1']) # area x1,y1,x2,y2
        st.table(df_raw)
    os.remove(tmp.name)
```